# Calculate the fastest 50 km ride

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have these speed data from my cycling computer:

```
declare @DistanceTable Table
(
  Time DateTime2,
  DistanceMeters float
)

insert into @DistanceTable   values 
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:52.0000000',  2.10999989509583),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:53.0000000',  4.84999990463257),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:54.0000000',  7.94000005722046),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:55.0000000', 11.5600004196167),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:56.0000000', 16.2700004577637),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:57.0000000', 21.3199996948242),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:58.0000000', 26.9099998474121),
    ('2018-07-26 07:04:59.0000000', 32.8899993896484),
    ('2018-07-26 07:05:00.0000000', 39),
    ('2018-07-26 07:05:01.0000000', 45.6500015258789),
```

...

```
('2018-07-26 08:36:08.0000000', 50003.19921875),
('2018-07-26 08:36:09.0000000', 50010.73046875),
('2018-07-26 08:36:10.0000000', 50018.328125),
('2018-07-26 08:36:11.0000000', 50025.9609375),
('2018-07-26 08:36:12.0000000', 50033.5703125),
('2018-07-26 08:36:13.0000000', 50041.2109375),
('2018-07-26 08:36:14.0000000', 50048.94140625),
('2018-07-26 08:36:15.0000000', 50056.7109375),
('2018-07-26 08:36:16.0000000', 50064.421875),
('2018-07-26 08:36:17.0000000', 50072.1484375)
```

And a lot more data.

My question is: How do I calculate the fastest 50 km time in this track.

Scope: Sql Server 2017

Comment: I don't understand your data. How would you do it manually given this data set? What is a "Track" in this data?

Comment: You need a start/end time for each race, or is there a start time that is fixed for all of them?  Then using that start time, you compare to all times in your data to get how fast they went?

Comment: The first 50 km time (and so far the fastest)  :  '2018-07-26 08:36:08.0000000' - '2018-07-26 07:04:52.0000000'

So after 1 hour and 32 minuts

Comment: For each row after 50000 meters I want to calculate the distance in time to 50000 meters before.

Comment: Are you saying you want to compare 0 to 50000 with, 2 to 50002 and so on? Or did I misread this and you really want to compare 0 to 50k with 50k to 100k and so on?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt . . . You have an irregular time series.  This is going to be hard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know thats why I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by finding the first row after 50 km (in `cte`) and  group the results with `min()` and `max()`. Then I calculated a difference in seconds between `min` and `max` and converted it to time data type. I assumed that there can be only one ride per day, unless you are a superhuman...

```
  ;with mostCloseTo50 as (
    select
         Time
        ,row_number() over (partition by cast(Time as date) order by DistanceMeters asc) as number
        ,DistanceMeters
    from @DistanceTable
    where DistanceMeters > 50000
)
select 
    cast(dateadd(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND, min(d.Time), max(d.Time)),'00:00:00') as time(0))
from @DistanceTable as d
join mostCloseTo50 as m
    on cast(m.Time as date) = cast(d.Time as date)
    and m.number = 1
    and d.DistanceMeters <= m.DistanceMeters
group by cast(d.Time as date)
```

the result:

```
01:31:16
```

Comment: I'll try it out. Now I have some thing to work with.  This is a part of a 200km tour. So I might hav gone faster form km 1 to 51 compared to km 2 to 52 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script. Maybe it is simpler for understanding. Results are all segments with length 50 km. Find min for field "TimeSegmentSec".

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_DistanceTable_DistanceMeters on #DistanceTable (DistanceMeters) 

Declare @Segment int=50000 -- 50 km
Select DT.DistanceMeters as 'Start',DT3.DistanceMeters as 'Finish',DT.Time as 'StartTime',DT3.Time as 'FinishTime'
    ,DATEDIFF(second,DT.Time,DT3.Time) 'TimeSegmentSec',DT3.DistanceMeters-DT.DistanceMeters 'LengthSegment'
from #DistanceTable DT
    cross apply 
    (Select Top 1 Time,DistanceMeters from #DistanceTable DT2 where DT2.DistanceMeters<=DT.DistanceMeters+@Segment order by DistanceMeters desc
    ) as DT3
where DT3.DistanceMeters-DT.DistanceMeters>@Segment-20 -- Exclude shorter segment
```